# adb Android shell on Windows 7

Tags: android, shell

I have just installed ADT on Windows 7, but know little to nothing of Linux and ash shell commands.

So how do you do this? (Preferably without rooting the device).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is usually no `sudo` on Android devices, if the device is rooted, you would find `su` to log as root.

A lot of it depends on what device you are trying to get access to.

BTW, that has nothing to do with Windows 7 having shell commands or not, when you run `adb`, those are commands running on the device itself.

If the device is not rooted and access to `/data` is restricted, you won't be able to access it.

Comment: You have my upvote. 
So Google released the ADT to help us develop Android apps, yet doesn't allow access to the apk install path (i.e. `/data`) without rooting the device? I haven't yet had the chance to read up on Linux, but are there any other ways around this restriction?

Comment: It's not really up to Google to give access to the /data folder, but more to the phone manufacturer (and in a lot of cases the operator like AT$T). Again, (AFAIK) the only way "around" this is the rooting of the device.

Comment: An example of using `su` in way like `sudo` (from my phone, running `dumpstate` / `bugreport`): `/system/xbin/su root sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db pragma user_version; select * from system; select * from secure; select * from global;`